# C : send different structures for one function argument

Tags: c, function, structure, abstract, arguments

I have a function that draws a circle using OpenGL, I would like to pass it a structure containing the x and y coordinates and the radius. The problem is this same function has to be used with 3 different structures all containing the coordinates, radius and some other things that the draw function doesn't use.

Is there some way to only have one argument for 3 different structures (only one is sent at a time).

I hope I've been enough precise.

PS : the functions have to be "abstract".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use a prototype like this:

```
void foo(char type, void *data);
```

Use the type to tell the function which struct to use the data as, and you're good.

```
struct c *prepareStructC(void);
//...
struct c *toto = prepareStructC();
foo('c', toto);
//...
void foo(char type, void *data)
{
  int x, y;
  switch (type)
  {
    case 'c':
      x = ((struct c*)data)->x;
      y = ((struct c*)data)->y;
      break;
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```

Second option, if you want to avoid a switch/case, and be able to add more struct types afterwards, without evolving foo, you can make sure all your structs **begin** with the necessary data, always in the same order, with the same type. This way you can make something like an "interface" from C++, and use abstract versions of the type:

```
struct abstract
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int radius;
}

struct a
{
  struct abstract abs;
  //... other data ...
}
struct b
{
  struct abstract abs;
  //... other data ...
}
struct c
{
  struct abstract abs;
  //... other data ...
}

//Two choices : either you have:
void foo(void *data)
{
  int x,y,r;
  x = ((struct abstract*)data)->x;
  y = ((struct abstract*)data)->y;
  r = ((struct abstract*)data)->radius;
  //...
}

//OR Smarter way:
void foo2(struct abstract *data)
{
  int x,y,r;
  x = data->x;
  y = data->y;
  r = data->radius;
}
//Calling foo2 with:
struct a *sa = prepareStructA();
struct b *sb = prepareStructB();
struct c *sc = prepareStructC();
foo2(sa->abs);
foo2(sb->abs);
foo2(sc->abs);
```

The second part of the second method allows you more flexibility, breaking down specific information in a subtype, enables you to put the `abs` part anywhere inside the struct a/b/c, and is better in the principle of a single purpose for a struct (Having coordinates and radius **and** other things inside a struct is not always the best.)

Comment: +1 for second option with smarter way: This is exactly how OO is implemented in C.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm going with the inclusion of a struct in a struct.

Answer (score 1):

Only if the function accepts a `void*` as the argument, and then you cast the `void*` to the correct pointer type in the function before dereferencing it to access the data within.

```
typedef enum
{
    type1, type2, type3
} datatype;

void foo(void* data, datatype type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case type1:
        // do something with data by casting it to the proper type
        break;

        // ... other cases here
    }
}
```

However, by doing so you will a) need to pass another argument that indicates the original type being casted to `void*` before being passed, and b) you are abandoning the type system which is hardly ever a good idea and should always be avoided.

If you take this approach, **highly** recommend creating three "wrapper" functions that take the correct types before calling the function (that takes the `void*`) internally. Make it a **strict** convention to never call the `void*` function directly; only call the wrapper. In this fashion, you still have the type system to help out with compilation errors.

```
void bar1(someStruct* data)
{
    foo((void*) data, type1);
}
void bar2(someOtherStruct* data)
{
    foo((void*) data, type2);
}
void bar3(yetAnotherStruct* data)
{
    foo((void*) data, type3);
}
```

Comment: You're right, the enum is better than a regular "char", my first method's dirtier ^^"

Comment: Agreed, but you make a good point with beginning the separate structs with the same data "signature", allowing for both use of the type system and (theoretically) fewer changes to the primary function over time.