# How to write C function accepting (one) argument of any type

Tags: c, types, variadic, any

I am implementing simple library for lists in C, and I have a problem with writing `find` function.

I would like my function to accept *any* type of argument to find, both:
`find(my_list, 3)` and `find(my_list, my_int_var_to_find)`.
**I already have information what is type of list's elements**.

For now I've found couple of ways dealing with this:

- different function with suffix for different types: `int findi(void* list, int i)`, `int findd(void* list, double d)` - but I don't like this approach, it seems like redundancy for me and an API is confusing.
- using union:

  ```
  typedef union {
     int i;
     double d;
     char c;
     ...
  } any_type;
  ```

  but this way I force user to both know about `any_type` union, and to create it before invocation of `find`. I would like to avoid that.
- using variadic function: `int find(void* list, ...)`. I like this approach. However, I am concerned about no restrictions on number of arguments. User is free to write `int x = find(list, 1, 2.0, 'c')` although I don't know what it should mean.

I have seen also answer to this question: [C : send different structures for one function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212655/c-send-different-structures-for-one-function-argument) but it's irrelevant, because I want to accept non-pointer arguments.

What is the proper way of handling this function?

Comment: I'd do approach #1 and utilize a macro using the new C11 `_Generic` for distinguishing type.

Comment: The mingw C compiler (Ive been using) doesnt do type checking on the arguments you pass it. At first I thought this only applied to wchart* and char*. But then I realized that functions that take an int can take char*, struct, any thing. Then the function crashes if it requires char* but got a random integer. Is this a bug or is this the standard?

Answer (score 9):

You could instead try implementing your function similar to a generic function like `bsearch`, which can perform a binary search on an array of any data type:

```
void *bsearch(const void *key, const void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
              int (*compar)(const void *, const void *))
```

Rather than hard-coding the different implementations for different data types inside your function, you instead pass a pointer to a function which will do the type-dependent operation, and only it knows the underlying implementation. In your case, that could be some sort of traversal/iteration function.

The other thing `bsearch` needs to know (apart from the obvious - search key and array length) is the size of each element in the array, so that it can calculate the address of each element in the array and pass it to the comparison function.

If you had a finite list of types that were to be operated on, there's nothing wrong with having a family of `findX()` functions. The above method requires a function for each data type to be passed to the `bsearch` function, however one of the main differences is that common functionality doesn't need to be repeated and the generic function can be used for *any* data type.

I wouldn't really say there's any *proper* way to do this, it's up to you and really depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: It really looks like the easiest way (at the first sight). For now I have finite list of types. But if I want to add another type I need to write another wrapper function. I don't think it's the best way how to solve this problem.

Comment: @BartekChaber: Yeah there's not really an elegant way to do what you're wanting in C, unlike templates in languages like C++ and Java. Making a generic function and passing around function pointers is how I usually go about it in my projects.

Comment: @AusCBloke: Depends in your requirements, if C11 is fine there's _Generic.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether answering my own question is polite, but I want your opinion.

I tried to solve this problem using va_list. Why so? Because this way I can write only one function. Please, mind that I **know what type the argument should be**. This way I can do this:

```
    int find(void* list, ...) {
      any_type object = {0};
      int i = -1;
      va_list args;
      va_start(args, list);
      switch(type_of_elem(list)) {
        case INT: object.i = va_arg(args, int); break;
        ...
      }
      /* now &object is pointer to memory ready for comparision
       * f.eg. using memcmp */
      return i;
    }
```

The advantage of this solution is that I can wrap presented switch-case and reuse it with other functions.

After researching a little bit more on my concern regarding no limit on number of arguments I realized that `printf` lacks this limit either. You can write `printf("%d", 1, 2, 3)`.
But I tweaked my solution with additional macro:

```
    #define find_(list, object) find((list), (object))
```

Which produces error message at compile time, saying that `find_ macro expects 2 arguments not 3`.

What do you think about it? Do you think this is better solution than previously suggested?

Comment: I would definitely go with the va_list approach.  I'm not certain whether the macro adds much.  The most likely problem is that someone will do `find(list, 12)` when the list is of doubles.  The macro still doesn't give a warning in that case.  Why would someone try to do `find(list, 1, 2.0, 'c')` anyway?

Comment: @asc99c Why? Because function's signature allows this :)
You are absolutely right about not being type safe when searching. I hope this is the only one disadvantage of this approach.